# for one price or one flat price?

Tags: grammar

I'm kind of confused about grammar here, and I wonder which one of the following sentences I should use for my website!

build unlimited websites for one price!

build unlimited websites for one flat fee!

build unlimited websites for one low price!

Thanks everyone for taking the time to help!

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: I don't really know which one suites me best, I would like to tell my customers that they can create unlimited number of websites for one flat fee, instead of paying for each.

Comment: Why don't you go a step further and give them some idea of what the price will be. 'Build unlimited websites for the price of a tablet'. If you proceed with that my consultancy fee will be $1,000 and 10% of your first-year's takings!

Comment: @WS2 (or $1,000,000 whichever is more).

Answer (score 1):

I a a fan of listing the said price you are offering the aforementioned websites for.

`Build Unlimited Websites for $19.99` for example.

That way there is absolutely no confusion.

Comment: I'm confused.  You'll build as many web sites as I want for $20?  That seems too good to be true.